# Вывод подменю в определенном месте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении мышью на пункт меню, всплывало подменю этого пункта в определенном месте на странице, как на рисунке.
[image: Уникма]

Comment: Приведите код того, что у вас уже готово

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fd2Lfrka/27/

Comment: код по ссылке явно не соответствует поставленной задаче

Comment: Может я что то не обновил, но вот еще раз. http://jsfiddle.net/fd2Lfrka/28/. Есть пункты меню, и рисунок с обозначенными на нем позициями вывода. При наведении на ссылки слева, должно отобразиться выпадающее меню на данной позиции на рисунке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение на jQuery:

В CSS вместо

```
.img-map>div>div:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

пропишите

```
.img-map>div>div:hover ul,
.img-map>div>div.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

В JS использовал уже добавленные вами атрибуты `data-class`.

```js
$('ul.fll a').on('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  var list = $(this).closest('li.hov').attr('data-class');
  $('.' + list).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.img-map {
  position: relative;
  margin: 65px 0 0;
}

.img-map>ul {
  color: #3daa35;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 265px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.img-map>ul a {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #094b81;
  margin-left: -5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.img-map>ul span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul span,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul span {
  margin-left: -52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img-map>ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul {
  width: 270px;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}

.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie10 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie9 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie8 .img-map>ul a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul li,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul li {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-map>ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img-map>div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 261px;
  top: -60px;
}

.img-map>ul li:hover {
  color: #fed209;
}

.img-map>ul li:hover a {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.img-map>div>div {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: #3caa37;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3caa37', endColorstr='#46ac2c', GradientType=0);
}

.img-map>div>div:hover {
  background: #fde732;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fde732', endColorstr='#ffc607', GradientType=0);
}

.img-map>div>div ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 17px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 17px 17px 17px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ebecec;
}

.img-map>div>div:hover ul,
.img-map>div>div.active ul {
  display: block;
}

.img-map>div>div.hoverclass ul {
  display: block;
}

.img-map>div>div ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*.img-map>div>div ul li:before {content: "â†’"; position: absolute; left: -23px; top: 0;}*/

.img-map>div>div ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 47px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #ebecec;
}

.map-list1 {
  left: 289px;
  top: 30px;
}

.map-list2 {
  left: 405px;
  top: 45px;
}

.map-list3 {
  left: 399px;
  top: 107px;
}

.map-list4 {
  left: 315px;
  top: 300px;
}

.map-list5 {
  left: 275px;
  top: 183px;
}

.map-list6 {
  left: 245px;
  top: 265px;
}

.map-list7 {
  left: 455px;
  top: 287px;
}

.map-list8 {
  left: 50px;
  top: 170px;
}

.map-list9 {
  left: 447px;
  top: 147px;
}

.map-list10 {
  left: 310px;
  top: 123px;
}

.map-list2 ul,
.map-list3 ul,
.map-list4 ul {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 17px;
}

.map-list2 ul:before,
.map-list3 ul:before,
.map-list4 ul:before {
  left: auto !important;
  right: -10px;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  border-left: 10px solid #ebecec !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:1200px">
  <div class="img-map clearfix">
    <div>
      <a href='https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=4055428d8952d97059a982941a17d175' title='хостинг картинок'><img style="width:100%" src='https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/07/4055428d8952d97059a982941a17d175.png' /></a>
      <div class="map-list1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dymokhodnye_sistemy/">Дымоходные системы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/metallocherepitsa/">Металлочерепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gibkaya_cherepitsa/">Гибкая черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/faltsevaya_krovlya/">Материалы для фальцевой кровли</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/tsementno_peschanaya_cherepitsa/">Цементно-песчаная черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/keramicheskaya_cherepitsa/">Керамическая черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/kompozitnaya_cherepitsa/">Композитная черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/prirodnyy_shifer_rathscheck/">Кровельный сланец</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/profnastil/">Профнастил</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/ondulin/">Ондулин</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/vodostoki/">Водосточные системы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/elementy_bezopasnosti/">Элементы безопасности</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/elementy_ventilyatsii/">Элементы вентиляции</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/okna_mansardnye/">Мансардные окна</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/cherdachnye_lestnitsy/">Чердачные лестницы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/krovelnye_komplektuyushchie/">Кровельные комплектующие</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list4">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_dlya_fasadnykh_rabot/">Растворы для фасадных работ</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_dlya_moshcheniya/">Расворы для укладки брусчатки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dlya_napolnoy_plitki/">Расворы для укладки напольной плитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/remontnye_shtukaturki_i_shpaklevki/">Ремонтные шпаклевки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_i_klei_dlya_kladki_/">Клей для стеновых блоков</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gidroizolyatsiya_1/">Гидроизоляция</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/klei_dlya_plitki_1/">Клеи для плитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zatirki_1/">Затирки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/nalivnye_poly/">Наливные полы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list5">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gazobetonnye_bloki/">Газобетонные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/porizovannye_bloki/">Поризованные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/peregorodochnye_bloki/">Перегородочные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/odinarnyy_kirpich/">Одинарный кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dvoynoy_kirpich/">Кирпич 2,1 НФ и 4,5 НФ</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/polnotelyy_kirpich/">Полнотелый кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/peremychki_dlya_okonnykh_i_dvernykh_proemov/">Перемычки для оконных и дверных проемов</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dugoobraznye_bloki/">Дугообразные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/sborno_monolitnye_perekrytiya/">Сборно-монолитные перекрытия</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/instrument/">Крепеж и инструмент</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list6">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/oblitsovochnyy_kirpich/">Облицовочный кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/shtukaturnyy_fasad/">Штукатурный фасад</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/sayding/">Сайдинг</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/oblitsovochnaya_plitka/">Облицовочная плитка</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/iskusstvennyy_kamen/">Искусственный камень</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/fasadnye_paneli/">Фасадные панели</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/kraski/">Краски</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list7">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_klinkernaya/">Брусчатка клинкерная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_betonnaya/">Брусчатка бетонная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_ruchnoy_formovki/">Брусчатка ручной формовки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_mozaichnaya/">Брусчатка мозаичная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/ekspluatiruemyy_gazon/">Эксплуатируемый газон</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/geosintetiki/">Геосинтетики</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/plitka_napolnaya_i_stupeni/">Плитка напольная и ступени</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/terrasnye_plity/">Террасные плиты</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bordyury_i_vodootvody/">Бордюры и водоотводы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list8">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zabory_iz_profnastila/">Заборы из профнастила</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/modulnye_zabory/">Модульные заборы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zabory_iz_svarnykh_paneley/">Заборы из сварных панелей</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="map-list9">
   <ul>
       </ul>
  </div> -->
      <div class="map-list10">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/utepliteli/">Утеплители</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/izolyatsionnye_materialy/">Изоляционные материалы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="map-list15">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/catalog/utepliteli/">Утеплители</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<div class="map-list16">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/catalog/izolyatsionnye_materialy/">Изоляционные материалы</a></li>
   </ul>
</div> -->

    </div>
    <ul class="fll">
      <!--   <li><a href="">Кровельные материалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Фасадные материалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Заборы и ограждения</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тротуары</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Стеновые материалы</a></li>
 -->
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list2">
        <a href="/catalog/#Кровельные_материалы">Кровельные материалы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list3">
        <a href="/catalog/#Обустройство_кровли">Обустройство кровли</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list5">
        <a href="/catalog/#Стеновые_материалы">Стеновые материалы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list6">
        <a href="/catalog/#Фасадные_материалы">Фасадные материалы</a>
      </li>


      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list7">
        <a href="/catalog/#Тротуары">Тротуары</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="flr">
      <!--   <li><a href="">Изоляция</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Элементы безопасности</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Дымоходы и вентканалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Водосточные системы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Мансардные окна</a></li>
 -->
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list15">
        <a href="/catalog/#Утепление_и_изоляция">Утепление и изоляция</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list4">
        <a href="/catalog/#Cтроительные_смеси">Строительные смеси</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list8">
        <a href="/catalog/#Заборы">Заборы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list1">
        <a href="/catalog/#Дымоходные_системы">Дымоходы</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li class="hov" data-class="map-list9">
    <a href="/catalog/elementy_bezopasnosti/">Элементы безопасности</a>
   </li> -->


    </ul>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE** с учетом комментария про добавление задержки исчезновения:

```js
var delay;
$('ul.fll a').on('mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout(delay);
  $('.map-list').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + $(this).closest('li.hov').attr('data-class')).addClass('active');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  var link = $(this);
  delay = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.' + link.closest('li.hov').attr('data-class')).removeClass('active');
  }, 3000); // время задежки в миллисекундах
});
```

```css
.img-map {
  position: relative;
  margin: 65px 0 0;
}

.img-map>ul {
  color: #3daa35;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 265px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.img-map>ul a {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #094b81;
  margin-left: -5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.img-map>ul span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul span,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul span {
  margin-left: -52px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img-map>ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul {
  width: 270px;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}

.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie10 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie9 .img-map>ul a,
.bx-ie8 .img-map>ul a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.bx-ie .img-map>ul li,
.bx-ie11 .img-map>ul li {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-map>ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img-map>div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 261px;
  top: -60px;
}

.img-map>ul li:hover {
  color: #fed209;
}

.img-map>ul li:hover a {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.img-map>div>div {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: #3caa37;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3caa37 0%, #46ac2c 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3caa37', endColorstr='#46ac2c', GradientType=0);
}

.img-map>div>div:hover {
  background: #fde732;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fde732 0%, #ffc607 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fde732', endColorstr='#ffc607', GradientType=0);
}

.img-map>div>div ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 17px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 17px 17px 17px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ebecec;
}

.img-map>div>div:hover ul,
.img-map>div>div.active ul {
  display: block;
}

.img-map>div>div.hoverclass ul {
  display: block;
}

.img-map>div>div ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*.img-map>div>div ul li:before {content: "â†’"; position: absolute; left: -23px; top: 0;}*/

.img-map>div>div ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 47px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #ebecec;
}

.map-list1 {
  left: 289px;
  top: 30px;
}

.map-list2 {
  left: 405px;
  top: 45px;
}

.map-list3 {
  left: 399px;
  top: 107px;
}

.map-list4 {
  left: 315px;
  top: 300px;
}

.map-list5 {
  left: 275px;
  top: 183px;
}

.map-list6 {
  left: 245px;
  top: 265px;
}

.map-list7 {
  left: 455px;
  top: 287px;
}

.map-list8 {
  left: 50px;
  top: 170px;
}

.map-list9 {
  left: 447px;
  top: 147px;
}

.map-list10 {
  left: 310px;
  top: 123px;
}

.map-list2 ul,
.map-list3 ul,
.map-list4 ul {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 17px;
}

.map-list2 ul:before,
.map-list3 ul:before,
.map-list4 ul:before {
  left: auto !important;
  right: -10px;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  border-left: 10px solid #ebecec !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:1200px">
  <div class="img-map clearfix">
    <div>
      <a href='https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=4055428d8952d97059a982941a17d175' title='хостинг картинок'><img style="width:100%" src='https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/07/4055428d8952d97059a982941a17d175.png' /></a>
      <div class="map-list map-list1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dymokhodnye_sistemy/">Дымоходные системы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/metallocherepitsa/">Металлочерепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gibkaya_cherepitsa/">Гибкая черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/faltsevaya_krovlya/">Материалы для фальцевой кровли</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/tsementno_peschanaya_cherepitsa/">Цементно-песчаная черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/keramicheskaya_cherepitsa/">Керамическая черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/kompozitnaya_cherepitsa/">Композитная черепица</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/prirodnyy_shifer_rathscheck/">Кровельный сланец</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/profnastil/">Профнастил</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/ondulin/">Ондулин</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/vodostoki/">Водосточные системы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/elementy_bezopasnosti/">Элементы безопасности</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/elementy_ventilyatsii/">Элементы вентиляции</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/okna_mansardnye/">Мансардные окна</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/cherdachnye_lestnitsy/">Чердачные лестницы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/krovelnye_komplektuyushchie/">Кровельные комплектующие</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list4">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_dlya_fasadnykh_rabot/">Растворы для фасадных работ</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_dlya_moshcheniya/">Расворы для укладки брусчатки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dlya_napolnoy_plitki/">Расворы для укладки напольной плитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/remontnye_shtukaturki_i_shpaklevki/">Ремонтные шпаклевки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/rastvory_i_klei_dlya_kladki_/">Клей для стеновых блоков</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gidroizolyatsiya_1/">Гидроизоляция</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/klei_dlya_plitki_1/">Клеи для плитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zatirki_1/">Затирки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/nalivnye_poly/">Наливные полы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list5">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/gazobetonnye_bloki/">Газобетонные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/porizovannye_bloki/">Поризованные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/peregorodochnye_bloki/">Перегородочные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/odinarnyy_kirpich/">Одинарный кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dvoynoy_kirpich/">Кирпич 2,1 НФ и 4,5 НФ</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/polnotelyy_kirpich/">Полнотелый кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/peremychki_dlya_okonnykh_i_dvernykh_proemov/">Перемычки для оконных и дверных проемов</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/dugoobraznye_bloki/">Дугообразные блоки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/sborno_monolitnye_perekrytiya/">Сборно-монолитные перекрытия</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/instrument/">Крепеж и инструмент</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list6">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/oblitsovochnyy_kirpich/">Облицовочный кирпич</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/shtukaturnyy_fasad/">Штукатурный фасад</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/sayding/">Сайдинг</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/oblitsovochnaya_plitka/">Облицовочная плитка</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/iskusstvennyy_kamen/">Искусственный камень</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/fasadnye_paneli/">Фасадные панели</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/kraski/">Краски</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list7">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_klinkernaya/">Брусчатка клинкерная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_betonnaya/">Брусчатка бетонная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_ruchnoy_formovki/">Брусчатка ручной формовки</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bruschatka_mozaichnaya/">Брусчатка мозаичная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/ekspluatiruemyy_gazon/">Эксплуатируемый газон</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/geosintetiki/">Геосинтетики</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/plitka_napolnaya_i_stupeni/">Плитка напольная и ступени</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/terrasnye_plity/">Террасные плиты</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/bordyury_i_vodootvody/">Бордюры и водоотводы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="map-list map-list8">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zabory_iz_profnastila/">Заборы из профнастила</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/modulnye_zabory/">Модульные заборы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/zabory_iz_svarnykh_paneley/">Заборы из сварных панелей</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="map-list9">
   <ul>
       </ul>
  </div> -->
      <div class="map-list map-list10">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/catalog/utepliteli/">Утеплители</a></li>
          <li><a href="/catalog/izolyatsionnye_materialy/">Изоляционные материалы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="map-list15">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/catalog/utepliteli/">Утеплители</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<div class="map-list16">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/catalog/izolyatsionnye_materialy/">Изоляционные материалы</a></li>
   </ul>
</div> -->

    </div>
    <ul class="fll">
      <!--   <li><a href="">Кровельные материалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Фасадные материалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Заборы и ограждения</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тротуары</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Стеновые материалы</a></li>
 -->
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list2">
        <a href="/catalog/#Кровельные_материалы">Кровельные материалы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list3">
        <a href="/catalog/#Обустройство_кровли">Обустройство кровли</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list5">
        <a href="/catalog/#Стеновые_материалы">Стеновые материалы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list6">
        <a href="/catalog/#Фасадные_материалы">Фасадные материалы</a>
      </li>


      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list7">
        <a href="/catalog/#Тротуары">Тротуары</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="flr">
      <!--   <li><a href="">Изоляция</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Элементы безопасности</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Дымоходы и вентканалы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Водосточные системы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Мансардные окна</a></li>
 -->
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list15">
        <a href="/catalog/#Утепление_и_изоляция">Утепление и изоляция</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list4">
        <a href="/catalog/#Cтроительные_смеси">Строительные смеси</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list8">
        <a href="/catalog/#Заборы">Заборы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hov" data-class="map-list1">
        <a href="/catalog/#Дымоходные_системы">Дымоходы</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li class="hov" data-class="map-list9">
    <a href="/catalog/elementy_bezopasnosti/">Элементы безопасности</a>
   </li> -->


    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!! Все просто замечательно работает!

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а можно ли чтобы выпадающие меню появлялись с некоторой задержкой, для того что бы успеть перевести на них курсор? Совсем не силен в Jquery. Пробывал на css, но эта реализация там работает коряво.

Comment: @FlapJack можно

Comment: $('.img-map>div>div ul ul').delay(150).slideUp(150); Похоже я что то неверно написал, поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: @FlapJack обновил ответ

Comment: К сожалению у вашего решения одна проблема(( Если быстро перемещаться по ссылкам меню, то подменю появляются, но не скрываются снова(

Comment: @FlapJack обновил ответ и поправил "проблему", если я верно ее понял

Comment: Прекрасно! То что нужно было! Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Вы замечательный человек